# How to draw monochrome text on bitmap with C#

Tags: c#, fonts, bitmap

I´d like to print monochrome text on bitmap, to be used in LED panel (1 bit per pixel). How can I use embedded bitmaps found in font?

I tried `g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.**AntiAlias**;`
But the result was terrible - I got distorted letters.

I find it easier to show what I want to do, rather than explain...

1. Open 2 paintbrush windows (pbrush.exe)
2. On the 1st pbrush, just print the letter A using the Calibri font,
   size 22.
3. On the 2nd pbrush, change settings to monochrome (Ctrl-E) and print
   the letter A.

As you can see in the image from  [**this link - I can´t post images yet...**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OXI.png) , the 2nd A is very well drawn because (I guess) it uses the embedded bitmap font in Calibri.

The next link shows the same result for  [**Courier New 12 on color bitmap and monochrome bitmap**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cn8n.png) 
There you will see that text drawn on monochrome bitmap has superb quality (due to the use of embedded bitmap font?)

Does pbrush use different methods to draw a text on color or monochrome bitmaps?

I did some heavy research, but could not find a code to mimmic pbrush drawing method.

(this post was edited to make it shorter and simpler)

Comment: You need to turn __off all__ anti-aliasing.

Comment: Set `g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`. `g.TextContrast = 12`. Draw the string with `StringFormat.GenericTypographic`.

Comment: The "g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit"" 
 and the   "g.TextContrast = 12" did the trick.  I later added "StringFormat.GenericTypographic", but I didn´t notice any improvements. I never thought there could be so much to simply draw a string... **THANKS, JIMI!!!**